# background color disappear when I delete overflow: hidden property from li{}

Tags: html, css, css-float, overflow

I'm trying a simple list layout, when I delete the `overflow:hidden` from `li {}`, the background color simply disappears. Because I'm new to CSS, I could be able to figure out why this is happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <style>
        ol {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: green;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        li {
            float: left
        }

        a{
            display: inline-block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li:hover {
            background-color: red;
        }


    </style>

    <body>
        <ol>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#iPhone">iPhone</a></li>
            <li><a href="#iPad">iPad</a></li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its a `clear:both` problem. The `ol` cant tell the height of the `li` as they are floating

Comment: since you're using float, you need the container to have `overflow: hidden` to cover the child elements, or you could use the clearfix tip: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/, but you could also set your li in `display: inline-block;` instead

Comment: Thank you so much guys for helping out! but I'm still a little bit confused about why this is happening? could you please explain it in a bit more detail? Sorry for been such a noob

Comment: @TonyStark i have mentioned why this issue is causing and what to do after using float. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are using float, keep in mind that you have to use `clear:both`. The reason why we use clear:both is that float property will break the flow of html element and will push them according to value(left,right), in  your case you have used float:left means all li will be in one line and if space will not covered then it will create blank space issue and to remove that blank space we use clear:both so any blank space which is left will be covered by using **clear:both**.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/sfpo6ksj/) I have used div to remove blank space.

For more detail you can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) and for detailed information see [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/u8v8ae9c/

The `float:left;` on your li-tags is causing the issue.

Comment: So we should remove the float?? instead of solving the issue?? OP is new and we can't say forget float.

Comment: Yeah, I tought the comments on the question were explanation enough and I was just providing a clear answer, but apparently I was wrong. 1+ Your answer

Answer (score 1):

You have floated the li element to left. Instead which you can use

**display:inline-block;**

```
 ol {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: green;
  }

    li {
       display:inline-block;
    }

    a{
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/u44Loz5z/